# Join two tables and select a row using foreign key SQL query

Tags: sql

I have two tables `Cities` and `Country`. I am using the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM citiesTable 
WHERE cityName LIKE 'F%' 
LIMIT 30
```

Each `cityName` has their respective country joined with foreign key in `country` table.

I want to select each city with and their respective country like Fayzabad , Afghanistan. Which query should I use? Please mention must since I am new to SQL

Comment: use join query to achieve your goal

Comment: Please avoid using images for describing data. Describe your database in, short form, in clear text, so it can be copy and pasted should someone wish to recreate the scenario.

Comment: ok thanks i am gonna delete the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join query

```
SELECT * 
FROM citiesTable, country 
WHERE country.country_id = citiesTable.country_id 
  AND cityName LIKE 'F%' LIMIT 30
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion marc_s

Comment: Update for marc_s comment link: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 2):

Better use left join to get all city table data

```
select city.*, ctry.countryName 
from citytable city 
left join country ctry on city.countryid = ctry.countryid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CitiesTable a, Country b 
WHERE a.country_id = b.id 
  AND a.cityName LIKE 'F%' 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged